# Reading the HTML and setting the text as a variable

Tags: javascript, html, url, dynamic

I am trying to set a banner on my site that basically reads a page number from the html (which I cant / wont edit) and changes the link within the banner to point to that page when clicked.

The point is to have a single banner that applies to all pages and a link that updates dynamically based on the page number in the html

The HTML I am looking for is found within the normal page :

```
<div class="left">
<p>
<strong>Page number</strong>
</p>
163
/
XXX
</div>
```

And the link simply needs to reflect the page e.g.

.../book.html

would update to

.../book.html?page=163

It is fine for it to simply go to the first page if it is a range, I'm just stuck for how best to achieve this.

Was going down this route

```
<a id="myAnchor">link me!</a> ... 

<script type="text/javascript"> var url = ".../book.html"; // .html is the new .com 
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor'); 
myAnchor.href = url; 
</script>
```

But can't figure a way to get the page number out to set it as a variable

Comment: Is the page number in the URL too?

Comment: The page number is not in the URL and I have been looking for the best way to achieve this to little effect. Most examples I have found rely on having the info in the URL

Comment: Was going down this route :<a id="myAnchor">link me!</a>

...

<script type="text/javascript">
var url = ".../book.html";  // .html is the new .com
var myAnchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
myAnchor.href = url;
</script>

But cant figure a way to get the page number out to set it as a variable

Comment: Oh, and most of what I did find relies on a FORM field like this one :
http://www.cryer.co.uk/resources/javascript/script8.htm

Comment: People - let the new SO member get a chance. - it is an OK question and there is an attempt to answer it too.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/BkqtJ/)

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var prefix = "Page number";
  var text = $('.left:contains("'+prefix+'")').text();

  if (text) $("#banner").html(text.split("/")[0]);
});
```

HTML:

```
<h1 id="banner"></h1>
<div class="left">
<p>
<strong>Page number</strong>
</p>
163
/
XXX
</div>
```

To get the number as a var:

```
if (text) {
  var number = parseInt(text.replace(prefix,"").split("/")[0],10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that mplug, going to have a play with that and see if it will work across my pages :)

Comment: I think that gets me nearer to what I want, but the result is passing all the content of that section, is there a way to strip the result back to just the numbers that are passed as the variable?

Comment: Second example does just that